# Como pegar o valor de varios campos preenchidos usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Atualmente tenho um sistema de busca de clientes que pode ser buscado por cpf, cnpj, telefone, endereco, email e varias outras informações, eu posso buscar um cliente perguntando se existe um cliente possuindo um email e um telefone,
a minha duvida e a seguinte, eu uso um tablist que tem um `form` e nesse `form` eu consigo pegar apenas o primeiro campo preenchido e não todos, no caso eu preciso pegar todos os campos que são preenchidos, exemplo:

```
<form  id='form_pesquisa'>
   <label for='nome'>Nome</label>
   <input type='text' name='nome' id='nome'/>
   <label for='email'>Email</label>
   <input type='text' name='email' id='email'/>
</form>

$("#nome,#email").change(function(){
  var search = $('#form_pesquisa').find(":text:visible").val();
  console.log(search);    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr34cmyr/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu seletor pode retornar vários itens (já que você está fazendo o seguinte com isso: `:text:visible` = selecione todos os `inputs` com `type` igual a `text` e que sejam visiveis), então você deve fazer um [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) neles precorrendo um a um e pegando seus respectivos valores, já que esse parece ser seu intuito, algo similar a isso:

```js
$("#nome,#email").change(function() {
  $('#form_pesquisa').find(":text:visible").each(function(i) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form_pesquisa'>
  <label for='nome'>Nome</label>
  <input type='text' name='nome' id='nome' />
  <label for='email'>Email</label>
  <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
</form>
```

[Exemplo online no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/tr34cmyr/3/)

Da maneira que você estava fazendo ao fazer um `.val()`em um seletor ele sempre irá retorna o valor (`value`) do item de índice 0 (o primeiro).

Como já descrito na própria [documentação do `.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/): "*Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.*", que em tradução literal seria: "Obtém o valor atual do primeiro elemento no conjunto de elementos agrupados."

Comment: sucesso, obrigado pelo conhecimento, há tempos que eu uso .val(); mas tinha me esquecido de usar o each() pra percorrer os campos pegando os valores.